# Create many rows and a single column from many columns

Tags: sql, unpivot

I am using SQL (in SAS). I have a dataset (table) that looks like this:

```
 Y1  Y2  Y3
100 200 300
```

What I would like to return is two columns that look like this:

```
Year  Value
1     100
2     200
3     300
```

What would be the SQL query to acheive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
SELECT y1 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT y2 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT y3 FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help. I can see how this will work.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2005+ you can use the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function:

```
select replace(col, 'Y', '') year,
  value
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (Y1, Y2, Y3)
) unpiv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8200/1)

This is the same process as using a `UNION ALL` query:

```
select 1 Year, Y1 value
from yourtable
union all
select 2 Year, Y2 value
from yourtable
union all
select 3 Year, Y3 value
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8200/3)

Both will produce the same result:

```
| YEAR | VALUE |
----------------
|    1 |   100 |
|    2 |   200 |
|    3 |   300 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a primary key on the row of, say, ID:

```
 ID   Y1  Y2  Y3
  1  100 200 300
```

Then this sort of thing should work

```
SELECT MOCKTABLE.* FROM (
   SELECT 1 AS Year, Y1 AS VALUE FROM x WHERE ID = y
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 AS Year, Y2 AS VALUE FROM x WHERE ID = y
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 3 AS Year, Y3 AS VALUE FROM x WHERE ID = y
) MOCKTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

A general way to unpivot columns is to create a cartesian product with a table that has as many rows in it as you require columns in the output. How you get this "table" depends on the RDBMS you are using. Here's an Oracle example:

```
select
r "Year",
case r when 1 then y1 when 2 then y2 when 3 then y3 else null end "Value"
from
t1, (select level r from dual connect by level <= 3)
```

Which gives:

```
Year  Value
1   100
2   200
3   300
```

Just another way of doing it...